# Laravel 5.7 ModelNotFoundException not return json for API calls

Tags: php, laravel

I want to return a json response when an api call is made to a laravel 5.7 app api route when the model is not found. To do this I have modified the `render()` method of `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` like this

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException && $request->wantsJson()) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```

and my controller `show()` method is using a `Book` model like this

```
public function show(Book $book)
    {
        return new BookResource($book->load('ratings'));
    }
```

Test on postman, a get call to `localhost:8000/api/books/1` (id 1 has been deleted) keeps returning the default laravel 404 not found page instead of json.

Have I missed a step or something? I also noticed that adding a conditional statement inside the  controller `show()` method like this

```
public function show(Book $book)
    {
        if ($book) {
            return new BookResource($book->load('ratings'));
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Not found'], 404);
        }
    }
```

returns the same html result instead of json.

What will be the proper way to handle this scenario?

Comment: The conditional statement doesn't trigger since the exception happens before since you are injecting the model.

Comment: What was the followed solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct. The problem is that you are probably testing it on a Local environment so in your .env you have set:

`APP_DEBUG=true`, switch it to `APP_DEBUG=false` and you will see your custom message.

PS: `$request->wantsJson()`  is not necessary if your clients send the correct header info, eg: `'accept:application/json'`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove  `$request->wantsJson`

or you can set the header in your request `"Accept" => "application/json"`

Comment: Result is still the same

Comment: What did you try ? Please also log the get_class($exception).

Answer (score -1):

May this can help you:

```
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException && ($request->wantsJson() || $request->ajax())) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Not Found!'], 404);
        }

        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
```